# There was an error parsing the query. How to resolve it?

Tags: c#, parsing, sql-server-ce, executenonquery

I want to run sql statement which I frist read from `.sql` file.

I'm getting this error:
`{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 13,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = ALTER ]"}`

There is my sql statement in `.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
   [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [DatabaseVersion] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   [Autorun] BIT,
   [CurrentCulture] NVARCHAR(10),
   [MailNotificationEnabled] BIT,
   [RefreshInterval] INT,
   [ModifiedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [schemat] NVARCHAR(255)
)

ALTER TABLE [Test] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])

UPDATE [AppConfig]
SET [DatabaseVersion] = '0.12'
```

Reading file:

```
string oldVersion = GetOldDatabaseVersion();
string sqlScript = "";
sqlScript = GetScriptFromAssembly(oldVersion, 
ConfigurationSettings.ValidDatabaseVersion);

ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sqlScript);
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` method:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType type, string sql)
{
    using (SqlCeConnection connection = CreateConnection())
    {
        return ExecuteNonQuery(connection, type, sql);
    }
}

private int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCeConnection connection, CommandType type, string sql)
{
    using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = type;
        command.CommandText = sql;

        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I doesn't know how to resolve it. When I run script dirctly on db it works.

Comment: I'd guess SqlCommand needs the command to be separated by `;`? It's just a guess because it seems not to recognize that `ALTER` starts a new statement.

Comment: I have tried it ;/

Comment: What I have now done - run each statement (create, alter etc.) separately. It works. Bu I doesn't want to create all statements in separate files ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run each statement as a seperate command, you can use code like the helper function to seperate into commands if you seperate each command with GO:

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/API/Repositories/ServerDBRepository.cs#L639

As you can see I am using `SqlCommandReaderStreamed` from the DbUp package to do this

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
string sqlScript = GetScriptFromAssembly(GetOldDatabaseVersion(), ConfigurationSettings.ValidDatabaseVersion);

string[] scripts = sqlScript.Split(new string[] { @"/*$$*/" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(var script in scripts)
    ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, script);
```

Added delimiters to sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
   [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [DatabaseVersion] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   [Autorun] BIT,
   [CurrentCulture] NVARCHAR(10),
   [MailNotificationEnabled] BIT,
   [RefreshInterval] INT,
   [ModifiedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [schemat] NVARCHAR(255)
)

/*$$*/
ALTER TABLE [Test] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])

/*$$*/
UPDATE [AppConfig]
SET [DatabaseVersion] = '0.12'
```

Answer (score -1):

- Please use the **Go** keyword before the Alter the table

Comment: afaik `GO` is **not** SQL and just used by tools like sql management studio to separate batches. But it's not transferred to the server, so it must not be part of the command text of an `SqlCommand`.